# LeetCode TwoSum runtime error: index -576 out of bounds for type 'int [10000]' Hash Table

Tags: c

On LeetCode the error is showing in the hash_search() function on the first line

```
if(hash_arr[(n + TABLE_SIZE/2) % TABLE_SIZE] != -1){}
```

My understanding is that somewhere during a LeetCode test run, there happens to be a negative index value which is not legal but I can't recreate where that happens. I am new to C but have searched extensively for this same type of error and would greatly appreciate any help with this index error.

Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TABLE_SIZE 10000

static int hash_arr[TABLE_SIZE];
int hash_insert();
void hash_init();
int hash_search();


// LeetCode function
//
// ret_arr[] is the array of two elements with the indices of the
// values that add up to the target value.
int *twoSum(int *nums, int numsSize, int target, int *returnSize){

    int i, j;
    int *ret_arr = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));

    // Validation
    if(ret_arr == NULL){
        *returnSize = 0;
        return NULL;
    }

    hash_init();

    for(i = 0; i < numsSize; i++){
        if((j = hash_search(target - nums[i])) == -1){
            hash_insert(nums[i], i);
        }else{
            // if j is already in the hash table
            ret_arr[0] = i;
            ret_arr[1] = j;
            *returnSize = 2;
            return ret_arr;
        }
    }
    *returnSize = 0;
    free(ret_arr);
    return NULL;
}

// int main(void) for testing purposes
int main(void){

    int nums[4] = {2,7,11,15};
    int numsSize = sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]);
    int returnSize = 0;
    int target = 9;
    int *p = NULL;

    p = twoSum(nums, numsSize, target, &returnSize);

    if(returnSize == 0){
        printf("Not found\n");
    }else{
        printf("Found at indices %d and %d\n", p[0], p[1]);
        free(p);
    }
}

// Initialization
void hash_init(){
    for(int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++){
        hash_arr[i] = -1;
    }
}


int hash_insert(int n, int j){
    // location available
    if(hash_arr[(n + TABLE_SIZE/2) % TABLE_SIZE] == -1){
        hash_arr[(n + TABLE_SIZE/2) % TABLE_SIZE] = j;
        return 0;
    }else{
        // if location already being used
        return -1;
    }
}

int hash_search(int n){
    if(hash_arr[(n + TABLE_SIZE/2) % TABLE_SIZE] != -1){
        return hash_arr[(n + TABLE_SIZE/2) % TABLE_SIZE];
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are "new to C" then I worry that you use leetcode to learn C and programming. Such sites (there are many) are ***not*** learning or teaching resources of any kind. They should be treated like the sudoku in the newspaper, as a simple brainteaser that you do if you have the time to spare and you feel like it. If you want to learn programming in general, then take computer science classes, and invest in books.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I am trying to learn C and C++ to break into the embedded systems/computer vision industry so maybe I should focus on other resources for learning!

Comment: If `n` itself can be negative then so can the array index `(n + TABLE_SIZE / 2) % TABLE_SIZE`. The result of `%` can be negative. Consider (I haven't seen the actual problem) doing sth like `(n + TABLE_SIZE + TABLE_SIZE/2) % TABLE_SIZE` so that modulus is always of a positive value.

Comment: See the last section of my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72511681/5382650 for a list of some resources