# Remove adjacent duplicates in doubly linked list in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list, function-definition

As the title mentioned, I have to remove adjacent duplicates in doubly linked list such that if input is 'google', the adjacent duplicates removal is google-->ggle-->le and hence output should be 'le'. I'm supposed to code it in C. I tried to perform delete operation as shown in this image-[image], except that I don't know how to continuously loop till all adjacent duplicates are removed (I don't know how to use recursion). I'm removing adjacent duplicates in remove_adjacent_duplicates() function, and since I don't know how to put terminating condition in loop, I've merely used while loop. I also don't know how to assign modified doubly linked list to original linked list named 'head', and so `head=current;` in while loop (line 63 of code) is a wrong assignment as it finally prints empty(?) list. Please rectify my mistakes and give correct solution. Here's my code-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};

struct node *head, *tail = NULL;  //Represent the head and tail of the doubly linked list  
int len;

void addNode(char data) {  
    struct node *newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //Create new node  
    newNode->data = data;  
     
    if(head == NULL) {      //If dll is empty  
        head = tail = newNode;  //Both head and tail will point to newNode  
        head->prev = NULL; //head's previous will point to NULL  
        tail->next = NULL;  //tail's next will point to NULL, as it is the last node of the list  
    }  
    else {  
        tail->next = newNode; //newNode will be added after tail such that tail's next points to newNode  
        newNode->prev = tail; //newNode's previous will point to tail  
        tail = newNode;  //newNode will become new tail  
        tail->next = NULL;  //As it is last node, tail's next will point to NULL  
    }  
}  

void remove_adjacent_duplicates() {  
    struct node *current, *index, *temp;  
    
    if(head == NULL) {  
        return;  
    }  
    else 
    {  
            current=head;
            while(current != NULL)  
            {  
                if(current->data == current->next->data) 
                {  
                    index = current->prev;  //noting data previous to duplicate data
                    //printf("%c\n",index->data);
                    
                    while(current->data == current->next->data && current!=NULL)
                    {
                        current=current->next; //iterating till all adjacent duplicates are found
                        //printf("*%c\n",current->data);

                    }
                    
                    temp=current->next; //temp points to character next to latest adjacent duplicate
                    //printf("!%c\n",temp->data);

                    index->next=temp; //the 'next' pointer of struct node of data before duplicate points to node after all adjacent duplicates found currently
                    //printf("@%c\n",index->data);

                    temp->prev=index; //data's 'prev' pointer (right after adjacent duplicates) points to data present just before adjacent duplicates
                    //printf("#%c\n",temp->data);

                    head=current; //logical error
                    //printf("$%c\n",head->data);

                    free(current);
                    free(index);
                    free(temp);
                    break;
                    
                }  
                
                else
                {
                    current=current->next;
                }
            }  
            
    }  
}

void display() {  
    struct node *current = head;  //head the global one
 
    while(current != NULL) {  
        printf("%c<->", current->data); //Prints each node by incrementing pointer.  
        current = current->next;  
    }  
   
    printf("NULL\n");  

}  

int main()
{
char s[100];
    int i;
   
    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%s",s);
    
    len=strlen(s);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        addNode(s[i]);
    }
     
    printf("Doubly linked list: \n");  
    display();  
     
    remove_adjacent_duplicates()   
    
    printf("Doubly linked list after removing adjacent duplicates: \n");  
    display();  
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should `gooogle` be transformed to `gogle` or to `le`?

Comment: Note that `current != NULL` does not imply that `current->next` is non-null, so `current->next->data` could be a null pointer dereference.

Comment: You don't need to recurse for this, and in fact, I would not recommend doing so.

Comment: @IanAbbott gooogle should be transformed to 'le'

Comment: Did you not find a solution to this [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74337915/2505965)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation that keeps a running count of adjacent nodes still to be removed.  This will have the value 0, 1 or 2.  It mostly advances forwards through the list except when the running count reaches 0 and a previous node exists, in which case it steps backwards one position:

**EDIT: This does not work for all cases. See reason why and a fix further down.**

```
void remove_adjacent_duplicates(void) {  
    struct node *current = head;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
    int remove = 0;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        next = current->next;
        if (next != NULL && next->data == current->data)
        {
            // Need to remove the current node and the next node.
            remove = 2;
        }
        if (remove != 0)
        {
            // Remove the current node.
            prev = current->prev;
            if (prev == NULL)
            {
                head = next;
            }
            else
            {
                prev->next = next;
            }
            if (next == NULL)
            {
                tail = prev;
            }
            else
            {
                next->prev = prev;
            }
            free(current);
            remove -= 1;  // Reduce running count of adjacent nodes to be removed.
            if (remove != 0)
            {
                // Next node will also be removed.
                // Step forward to next node.
                current = next;
            }
            else if (prev == NULL)
            {
                // No current plan to also remove the next node.
                // No previous node to step back to,
                // so step forwards to the next node.
                current = next;
            }
            else
            {
                // No current plan to also remove the next node.
                // Step backwards to the previous node.
                current = prev;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Not removing current node.  Step forwards to the next node.
            current = next;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: The problem with the above code.**

The above code fails to reduce `ggoogle` to `le`. The reason is that it has already removed the `gg` and the `oo` before it sees the next `g`.

**EDIT: A possible fix follows.**

One way to fix the problem is to extend `struct node` to include a flag which can be used as a temporary marker to defer the removal of one of the duplicate nodes. The first pass through the list can refer back to previous nodes that were duplicates.

```
struct node {
    char data;
    char flag;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};
```

Here is a version of `remove_adjacent_duplicates()` that uses the flag to mark duplicates that have not been removed yet, and which searches back when it encounters a node that isn't a duplicate to check if it can be paired up with an earlier node and marked for removal. A second pass then removes the nodes marked for removal:

```
void remove_adjacent_duplicates(void) {  
    struct node *current = head;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
    int remove = 0;

    // First pass.
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (remove == 0)
        {
            prev = current->prev;
            while (prev != NULL && prev->flag != 0 &&
                   prev->data != current->data)
            {
                prev = prev->prev;
            }
            if (prev != NULL && prev->data == current->data)
            {
                // Remove nodes from prev to current->prev inclusive.
                current->prev = prev->prev;
                prev->next = NULL;
                if (prev->prev == NULL)
                {
                    head = current;
                }
                else
                {
                    prev->prev->next = current;
                }
                do
                {
                    next = prev->next;
                    free(prev);
                    prev = next;
                }
                while (prev != NULL);
                current->flag = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                current->flag = 0;
            }
        }
        next = current->next;
        if (next != NULL && next->data == current->data)
        {
            // Need to remove the current node and the next node.
            remove = 2;
        }
        switch (remove)
        {
        case 2:
            // Remove the current node.
            prev = current->prev;
            if (prev == NULL)
            {
                head = next;
            }
            else
            {
                prev->next = next;
            }
            if (next == NULL)
            {
                tail = prev;
            }
            else
            {
                next->prev = prev;
            }
            free(current);
            remove--;
            break;
        case 1:
            // Mark the current node to be removed later.
            current->flag = 1;
            remove--;
            break;
        }
        current = next;
    }
    // Second pass - remove marked nodes.
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        next = current->next;
        if (current->flag != 0)
        {
            prev = current->prev;
            if (prev == NULL)
            {
                head = next;
            }
            else
            {
                prev->next = next;
            }
            if (next == NULL)
            {
                tail = prev;
            }
            else
            {
                next->prev = prev;
            }
            free(current);
        }
        current = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is harder than I thought. The above code reduces `ggoogle` to `gle` but it should be reduced to `le`. (The problem is that it has already removed the first two `g`s and the two `o`s before is sees the third `g`.) It really needs a mechanism to mark items to be removed from the list so that they are still available to be examined.

Comment: Added a fixed version, using temporary marker flags.

Comment: It still doesn't work for `googgle`. I give up for now!

Comment: And we're back! I think it might be working now. It reduces both `googgle` and `ggoogle` to `le`.

Comment: I discovered another bug. It reduces `googole` to `le`, but it should be reduced to `ole`. I'll add another comment when I've fixed it.

Comment: I fixed the `googole` case by removing previously marked nodes that have become enclosed by the backwards search.

Answer (score 1):

Truly speaking the task is very difficult for beginners as you and me.

Firstly it seems you think that in this declaration

```
struct node *head, *tail = NULL;  //Represent the head and tail of the doubly linked list
```

the both pointers are initialized explicitly by the specified initializer `NULL`.

Actually this declaration is not the same as

```
struct node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;  //Represent the head and tail of the doubly linked list
```

In the original declaration the pointer `head` will be initialized implicitly as a null pointer only because the declaration has the file scope. Otherwise you have to write

```
struct node *head = NULL, *tail = NULL;  //Represent the head and tail of the doubly linked list
```

to initialize the both pointers with `NULL`.

Further it is a bad idea when functions depend on global variables.

You should introduce one more structure as for example

```
struct list
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
};
```

that indeed will define a doubly linked list.

Also the declaration of the global variable `len` that is used only in main also is a bad style of programming and actually along with the call of `strlen` is redundant. You should declare variables in minimal scopes where they are used.

Your function `remove_adjacent_duplicates` is invalid at least because it does not change the pointers `head` and `tail`. They stay unchanged.

Or for example this while loop

```
        while(current != NULL)  
        {  
            if(current->data == current->next->data) 
            //...
```

can invoke undefined behavior when the list contains only one node because in this case you are dereferencing a null pointer in the condition of the if statement

```
current->next->data
```

The function can be defined the following wat as shown in the demonstration program below. I introduced one more structure as I already pointed out. The program does not use global variables.

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node 
{
    char data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};

struct list
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
};

int addNode( struct list *list, char data )
{
    struct node *newNode = malloc( sizeof( *newNode ) );
    int success = newNode != NULL;

    if (success)
    {
        newNode->prev = list->tail;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        newNode->data = data;

        if (list->head == NULL)
        {
            list->head = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            list->tail->next = newNode;
        }

        list->tail = newNode;
    }

    return success;
}

void display( const struct list *list )
{
    for (const struct node *current = list->head; current != NULL; current = current->next)
    {
        printf( "%c -> ", current->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

void reverse_display( const struct list *list )
{
    for (const struct node *current = list->tail; current != NULL; current = current->prev)
    {
        printf( "%c -> ", current->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

void remove_adjacent_duplicates( struct list *list )
{
    struct node **current = &list->head;

    while (*current != NULL)
    {
        if (( *current )->next && ( *current )->data == ( *current )->next->data)
        {
            struct node *tmp;

            // remove adjacent nodes with data equal to data of the current node
            while (( *current )->next && ( *current )->data == ( *current )->next->data)
            {
                tmp = ( *current )->next;
                if ( tmp->next != NULL)
                {
                    tmp->next->prev = tmp->prev;
                }
                ( *current )->next = tmp->next;
                free( tmp );
            }

            // remove the current node     
            if (( *current )->next == NULL)
            {
                list->tail = ( *current )->prev;
            }

            tmp = *current;
            if (tmp->next != NULL)
            {
                tmp->next->prev = tmp->prev;
            }
            *current = tmp->next;
            free( tmp );

            // step one back in the list
            if ( *current && ( *current )->prev)
            {
                current = ( *current )->prev->prev
                    ? &( *current )->prev->prev
                    : &list->head;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    struct list list = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };
    char s[100];

    printf( "Enter string: " );
    scanf( "%99s", s );

    for (char *p = s; *p; ++p)
    {
        addNode( &list, *p );
    }

    display( &list );
    reverse_display( &list );

    putchar( '\n' );

    remove_adjacent_duplicates( &list );

    display( &list );
    reverse_display( &list );

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter string: google
g -> o -> o -> g -> l -> e -> null
e -> l -> g -> o -> o -> g -> null

l -> e -> null
e -> l -> null
```

Comment: I think this has the same problem as my (deleted) answer. It reduces `ggoogle` to `gle` instead of `le`.

Comment: @IanAbbott ggoogle ->oogle ->gle. That is the correct result.:)

Comment: I disagree. If `gooogle` reduces to `le`, then so should `ggoogle`.

Comment: @IanAbbott gooogle => ggle -> le. It is not the same as ggoogle -> oogle -> gle.:)

Comment: But you could do ggoogle -> gggle -> le :)

Comment: @IanAbbott No you can not because the list is processed from its beginning. There is a sequential access not a random access.

Comment: Sequential in which direction? If you worked from the end towards the beginning you would get a different result. I think you should get the same result.

Comment: @IanAbbott Sequential is always from beginning. If you want from end then this is called reverse sequential access by analogy with C++ forward iterators and reverse iterators.:) So if you want to start from the tail of the list you need to write one more function  apart from the current function.

Comment: OP's question doesn't mention sequential access. It just mentions removing adjacent duplicates, including adjacent duplicates that result from removal of other adjacent duplicates.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thank you so much for your help and efforts! And regarding ggoogle I think both answers are acceptable since my professor who gave that question just asked us to traverse from left to right (which would be ggoogle-->oogle-->gle) or right to left (which would be ggoogle-->gggle-->le) according to our wish , so either way direction of traversing doesn't matter to him. He mainly wanted us to remove adjacent duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, here's your requirements:

1. delete a node from a list: you'll need to use list**
2. check if list contains two equal values: iterate from first to "last but 1", compare current with next
3. detect if deletion occured

pseudo code:

```
current node = list

while (current node != second last node)
{
  if (current node == next node) 
  {
    remove(next node) 
    current node = list
  } 
}
```

Not very efficient, but you got the idea.

The problem is you're trying to do multiple loops in a single function, this is fine usually but this way, if you need to jump at a specific position in your code (like, to restart a loop), you need a goto (which is HELL (most of the times))

Split the problem in smaller parts, you'll find out lists aren't that hard, what's putting you in troubles here is how the big block of code does too many things: delete_adjacent_duplicates() needs some remove_node() function.

delete_adjacent_duplicates() is responsible of detecting duplicates, the "delete node" part should be delegated.

If you can put a name on a list of instructions, make it a function.

Comment: I don't just want to remove duplicates, I want to remove all characters which are same and are adjacent to each other. So in 'haaal' I need to remove all a's and output should be 'hl'. Whereas in 'hala' the a's are not adjacent, so output is 'hala' only.

Comment: ```if current node == next node { while current node == next node { delete next node } delete current node }``` You mean like this ? What's the problem you're facing ?